# HTML Text containing numbers only

Tags: html

I have a textbox which should accept numbers only as this text is for roll number. My following code is serving my purpose.

```
<html>
<head><title>Sample Webpage</title></head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="roll_number" id="roll_number" value="25" placeholder="roll number" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am encountering a problem in Firefox. When I try to delete the roll number by using BACKSPACE/DELETE nothing is working. Its also not accepting these keys. But this is working fine in Chrome and IE. What should be the fix?

Comment: use ``<input type="number">``, as you mention you want HTML Text containing numbers only

Comment: @DonaldWu - number type is also accepting alphabets. In chrome its accepting "e" and in Firefox its accepting all the characters. Also MaxLength stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast solution is to check also if the pressed key is "Backspace", so you can modify your code with this:

```
<input type="text" name="roll_number" id="roll_number" value="25" placeholder="roll number" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.keyCode == 8'>
```

Comment: Keycode = 8 (Backspace) works fine but 127 for DELETE does not work.

Comment: @KPJoy  Delete should have keyCode 46, so try

    'return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 46'

In this way you allow arrow keys, backspace and delete.